# how to get instance name on object boolean which value is true

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, adobe-animate

i may have gone further than what i could
because i just learned actionscript 3 days ago.

I'm making a simple quiz where I made the answer choices manually, not using the components provided by Adobe Animate. because I can decorate the appearance however I want.

I made movieclip button named answer1 and answer2, then to check if the answer was selected I added a boolean.

```
e.currentTarget.selected = true;
e.currentTarget.selected = false;
```

this is my code for the answer button

```
function clicked(e:MouseEvent): void {
    if (e.currentTarget == answer1) {
        if (e.currentTarget.currentFrame == 1 ) {
        e.currentTarget.nextFrame(); // hover/active button
        e.currentTarget.selected = true;
        } else {
        e.currentTarget.prevFrame(); // hover/active button
        e.currentTarget.selected = false;
        }
        answer2.selected = false;
        answer2.prevFrame();
    } else if (e.currentTarget == answer2) {
        if (e.currentTarget.currentFrame == 1 ) {
        e.currentTarget.nextFrame(); // hover/active button
        e.currentTarget.selected = true;
        } else {
        e.currentTarget.prevFrame(); // hover/active button
        e.currentTarget.selected = false;
        }
        answer1.selected = false;
        answer1.prevFrame();
    }
}
```

then I made a button to check the answer. but until here I don't know how to check the object that has been selected

```
function checkAnswer(e: MouseEvent): void {
trace(answer1.selected.name)
}
```

i want only how can i get the instance name of the boolean object which has the value true.

Comment: Just **trace(answer1.selected);** is sufficient. Boolean values do not have names.

Comment: @Organis but how do I get the movieclip instance name if I trace it?

Comment: Try **trace(answer1.name);** I guess? The **name** is the property of the **MovieClip** itself, not its **Boolean** field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BTW, if you intend these selectors work as radiogroup (a group of radiobuttons that lets only one of them be selected as the same time), you'd better devise it that way:

```
function clicked(e:MouseEvent): void
{
    // Define a radiogroup.
    var aGroup:Array = [answer1, answer2];
    
    // Iterate over the group elements and process the click.
    for each (var anAnswer:MovieClip in aGroup)
    {
        if (anAnswer == e.currentTarget)
        {
            anAnswer.selected = !anAnswer.selected;
        }
        else
        {
            anAnswer.selected = false;
        }
        
        // Adjust the current frame according to "selected" value.
        if (anAnswer.selected)
        {
            anAnswer.nextFrame();
        }
        else
        {
            anAnswer.prevFrame();
        }
    }
}
```

Why? First, it is still shorter than yours even at 2 options. Second, think about adding more than 2 options, like, 10 of them? My code will only need extending the **Array** of options, yours will get 5 times longer than now.